# Custom attributes for a menu item

Tags: 8

I have to create a menu that includes items in a variety of languages including Arabic and Farsi.

Something like this:

```
-LTR item
-LTR item
 RTL item - 
-LTR item
 RTL item -
```

Is there a way to add the dir='rtl' to specific menu items?

And more importantly, is there a way for me to make this accessible to non-technical users that will be maintaining the site after I have created it?

The site is being built in Drupal 8

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe starting from https://www.drupal.org/project/link_attributes and contributing a dir attribute patch (this way you have a UI for non tech users that will maintain the site)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [hook_preprocess_HOOK](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.2.x)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function hook_preprocess_menu(&$variables) {
  $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'clearfix';
  if($variables['menu_name'] =='main'){
    foreach($variables['items'] as $item){
      if($item['title'] =='Home'){
        $item['attributes']['dir']='rtl';
      }
    }
  }
}
```